Spring Cloud Stream for SB3 tracing headers are Base64 encoded, makes it incompatible with SB2
When using micrometer with Spring Boot 3 and Sleuth with Spring Boot 2, we can make these two versions compatible for tracing. We can set to use b3 and w3c format together. It works fine, but there is one use case I have problem with.
When using Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka, headers in version 2021.0.x for Spring Boot 2 uses String plain text values for trace ids in headers b3 and traceparent, but version 2023.0.x for Spring Boot 3 encodes those values into Base64. So there is header b3: ==BASE64_ENCODED_VALUE==. When using SB3 to SB3 or SB2 to SB2 it works fine but when I send message from SB3 to SB2 and vice versa, the trace context is not set from headers.
Is there any solution to make it compatible, so we can set correct context in SB2 and SB3 consumers? Ideally tell somehow to SB3 to not encode values to Base64.

Can you double check what spring-kafka version is used there? We have some fix for headers mapping, which passed already couple releases: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/3286

I upgraded Spring Kafka version from 3.1.3 to the latest 3.2.2 and also the latest Spring Integration Kafka. Now I'm facing issue contentType header is byte[] for consumers, but traceparent is string. For SB2->SB3 it still does not set it to trace context same as before. I'm not sure why. I will try to play with BinderHeaderMapper if there is combination for both that could make it compatible together.
